# how to start jbpm process from drools rule?

Tags: java, drools, jbpm

I'm trying to write a rule that starts a business process, something like this:

```
rule "start workflow"
when 
$event : StartWorkflow()
then
 //start workflow
end
```

So far I managed to do this by passing the kieSession as a global to the drl and then doing this :

```
global KieSession kSession;

 
declare StartWorkflow
   workflowName : String

end
rule "start workflow"
    when
        $event : StartWorkflow()
    then
        kSession.startProcess($event.getWorkflowName());
        
end
```

But I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this using jbpm.

I saw that there was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385070/how-to-call-jbpm-process-from-drools-rule) with a similar title but it was about a different requirement.

Comment: Note that you could do `StartWorkflow( $name: workflowName )` in your when clause, and then `kSession.startProcess($name)` in the then.

Comment: What is your motivation/use-case to do this? The reason why I am asking is that it is generally not recommended to put such a heavy weight operation in the right hand side of the rule. You might run into all kinds of problems - what if that action will fail, how will that affect rule processing?